# How to reference Win 8 DLLs on a Win 7 machine?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, dependencies, dllimport

I am trying to reference a dll in my project (black box provided by a third company), but the dll does not load so I ma using depends.exe to check any dependecies.

I have found out that the dll internally is missing the following dlls (I believe are Win 8 DLLs, please tell me if I am wrong).

I am using Visual Studio on a Win 7 64 bit machine.

My questions:

- How can I load this dll on Win 7?
- Do I need work on Win 8 Machine?

  API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-L1-1-0.DLL

  ```
  API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-0.DLL
  API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL
  API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ROBUFFER-L1-1-0.DLL
  API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
  API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-SCALING-L1-1-1.DLL
  DCOMP.DLL
  IESHIMS.DLL
  ```

Comment: 1) They're part of Windows 8 RT, you **can not** use them with Windows 7 (even if, try to imagine, you'll copy them all on a Windows 7 machine). No way, forget it. 2) Yes, you must (strictly speaking you may compile on a Windows 7 machine but you'll always need Windows 8 to run/debug your program...)

Comment: please guys add a comment if you downvote